# WordPress posts are not showing at all

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have tried several codes to display WordPress posts in my theme I create but nothing works - why?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="postmetadata">
                <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
                Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | 
                <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
            </div>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h2>Not Found</h2>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php

if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
         the_content();
   endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Nothing is showing the posts why? I have the following files in my theme: index.php, header.php, style.css, footer.php, page.php, single.php

Comment: Do your pages show up as expected? Do you get a white screen when trying to view posts? Have you checked your error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME', // Add your post-type name
        'showposts' => 10 
    ) );  
?>
```

Please add this code in your above If statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status'=>'publish'
);
$wpquery = new WP_Query($args);     
if ($wpquery->have_posts()) : while ($wpquery->have_posts()) : $wpquery->the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

<div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<div class="postmetadata">
    <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
    Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | 
    <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
</div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

<h2>Not Found</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php

if ($wpquery->have_posts()) :
while ($wpquery->have_posts()) :
the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
endif; ?>
```